# CakePHP: Element or Helper

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a blog using CakePHP (2.2.x) and one part of the blog is the sidebar. A sidebar like the wordpress one with recent posts, archives and meta. I'm not sure if I should use an element or a helper for the sidebar.

For the moment I'm using an element. Some code snippets:

**Controller/PostsController.php**

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}

public function show($id) {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->findById($id));
}
```

**View/Posts/index.ctp**

```
<div class="span8">
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ... } ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->element('sidebar', array('posts' => $posts)); ?>
```

**View/Posts/show.ctp**

```
<div class="post">
   ... render the post using $post ...
</div>
<?php echo $this->element('sidebar', array('posts' => $posts)); ?>
```

**View/Elements/sidebar.ctp**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ... render the recent posts ... } ?>
```

As you can see, both `show.ctp` and `index.ctp` include `sidebar.ctp` element and both need `$posts` variable. So I need to call `$this->Post->find('all')` in both `index` and `show` actions. 
I would like to call `$this->Post->find('all')` **just once** and I wondering if using Helpers could, well, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `requestAction()`:

> You can take full advantage of elements by using requestAction(). The
>   requestAction() function fetches view variables from a controller
>   action and returns them as an array. This enables your elements to
>   perform in true MVC style. Create a controller action that prepares
>   the view variables for your elements, then call requestAction() inside
>   the second parameter of element() to feed the element the view
>   variables from your controller.

You can read more about them here:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element

Basically, you just specify where you want your element to retrieve it's data.  When the element loads (regardless of on which page), it will run the specified action to retrieve whatever data you want it to have.

Comment: Yes, that fits well. Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware that requestAction is slow. It's a full request in size, at least is the case in v2.x.